# Importing pairings of column data into sql from a csv

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have data given to me in the arrangement below, the timestamps appear to be the same going down the column but there's no way to actually export the data in such a way in where you're just given one timestamp on a single column. How do I go about keeping the pairs of data relevant?

```
    Timestamp, pizza shop, Timestamp, clothes store, Timestamp, stadium
    7/1/2019 0:00:00, 2, 7/1/2019 0:00:00, 4, 7/1/2019 0:00:00, 5
    7/1/2019 0:00:10, 3, 7/1/2019 0:00:10, 6, 7/1/2019 0:00:10, 7
```

Comment: Can you clarify how pairs of data are relevant to each other?  When you say "there's no way" do you mean for a program or a human?

Comment: The source I'm pulling this from hands me data in one of two formats:
1. As shown above

2. Or separately but you must individually select it from a database that I can't use to interact with my own (I'm working on trying to bring together multiple databases that export different representations of data).

My overarching problem is the different ways I have to merge these different representations and this just happens to be one of them. The timestamps appear to be the same for I was wondering if it was possible to grab this data without manually entering each location.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) to mount the csv file as a table, then use it to select into another table.

For example:

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;

CREATE SERVER files FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE csvfile (
  pizzashop_ts timestamp with time zone,
  pizzashop_count int,
  clothesstore_ts timestamp with time zone,
  clothesstore_count int,
  stadium_ts timestamp with time zone,
  stadium_count int)
SERVER files 
OPTIONS ( filename '/path/to/csv.file', format 'csv', header 'true');
```

And then we select from the table multiple times but only column pairs as a time, combine them all with UNION ALL, then add a "source" column to categorise the data:

```
SELECT pizzashop_ts AS "timestamp", pizzashop_count AS "count", 'pizza shop' AS source
FROM csvfile
UNION ALL
SELECT clothesstore_ts, clothesstore_count, 'clothes store' AS source
FROM csvfile
UNION ALL
SELECT stadium_ts, stadium_count, 'stadium' AS source
FROM csvfile;
```

This should lay out your CSV file like so:

```
       timestamp        | count |    source
------------------------+-------+---------------
 2019-07-01 00:00:00+01 |     2 | pizza shop
 2019-07-01 00:00:10+01 |     3 | pizza shop
 2019-07-01 00:00:00+01 |     4 | clothes store
 2019-07-01 00:00:10+01 |     6 | clothes store
 2019-07-01 00:00:00+01 |     5 | stadium
 2019-07-01 00:00:10+01 |     7 | stadium
(6 rows)
```

Naturally, you would turn this into an INSERT query to insert the data into a suitable table.

Disclosure: I am an EnterpriseDB (EDB) employee.

Comment: If we assume that we have a much larger dataset (40 different locations) in which manually selecting locations is inefficient, is there some logical statement that can allow me to skip through or is there no way to accomplish this?